# How to  post  scheduled posts on my friend's wall in facebook

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

I want to post updates or messages about my application to my friends. How can I post updates or messages on a friend's wall at specified time interval?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you've got to go for a cron job.